# Toggle button in HTML and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am implementing a sample application and I need to implement a follow button similar to the one in Twitter.

I have coded the button as follows,

```
<button class="btn pull-right{{setButtonStyle(S.Id)}}" 
ng-class="{true:'btn-primary', false:'btn-secondary'}[!S.isFollow]"
ng-click="toggleFollow(S.Id)"> {{!S.isFollow && 'Follow' || 'Unfollow'}}
</button>
```

The `ng-click` function handles the DB tables and also toggles the button UI. It is as follows,

```
$scope.toggleFollow = function (userId) {
    var element = $scope.followIds.indexOf(userId);
    if (element == -1) {
        // Follow user
        $scope.Searched[Sindex].isFollow = !$scope.Searched[Sindex].isFollow; // Toggles the button
        console.log("Follow called"); 
        })
    } else if (element > -1) {
        // Unfollow user
        $scope.Searched[Sindex].isFollow = !$scope.Searched[Sindex].isFollow; // Toggles the button
        console.log("Unfollow called"); 
        })
    }
}
```

The issue is that the button does not toggle at random. I suspect that the AngularJS digest loop doesn't fire every time the button is clicked.

I know for sure that the Angular function gets called every time when the button is clicked. So only the toggle doesn't fire as expected. So how do I force toggle the button every time it is clicked?

Comment: Try $scope.$apply() in the last function line

Comment: @Lax Did. I am getting an error that reads `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: Can you post plnkr or something else?

Comment: I am not familiar with Plunker. Nor do I have any idea about how I can simulate a DB on Plunker to reproduce the exact behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In your case ,its best to use angular's **$apply()**

**$apply**- is used to execute some code at first and then call the **$digest()** method internally , so that all **watches** are checked and the corresponding **watch listener functions** are called.

You make this happen in 2 ways.

**First approach**- use **$apply(), without arguments** at the end of your button's implementation code, like below example

```
$scope.toggleFollow = function (userId) {
   if (element == -1) {

       //...your button's implementation code

   }
   else if (element >= -1) {

      //....your button's implementation code

   }

   //Call $apply()
   $scope.$apply();

}
```

**Second Approach (recomended)**- write the button's implementation code inside the **function** (ie.the function that is passed as a parameter to $apply), so that, the function executes first, and ones function exits, AngularJS will call the **$digest()** ,so that all watches are checked for the changes in the watched values..

```
 $scope.toggleFollow = function (userId) {

   //Call $apply() ,passing the function as parameter
   $scope.$apply(function(){
         if (element == -1) {

           //...your button's implementation code

        }
        else if (element >= -1) {

             //....your button's implementation code

        }  
     });
}
```

For more information on **$apply**, refer [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) document. It would give you a better understanding and working of it.

Hope this helps out.

Cheers

Comment: Method 1 gives me an error that reads `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` after the function executes. Method 2 gives the same error but before the function executes.